# Does Automated Commit are ignored by workflow hook?

Tags: github, github-actions

We have two workflow that trigger on push set up like this:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
```

Inside of one workflow, it contains an action that push a bump version commit into master. 
Inside of the other, it validate if the commit message is a bump and deploy automatically.

Currently, when we push a commit to master, we can see the github action created a commit in master like this:

```
Automated Version Bump ci: version bump to v1.2.3
```

Where **Automated Version Bump** is the name of the GitHub action and **ci: version bump to v1.2.3** is the commit message generated by the GitHub action

I was expecting the workflow to trigger again because of the automated commit.

Does that means **Automated Commit** does not trigger workflow hook?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this behaviour is a feature.

From the workflow [events](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#about-workflow-events) page:

> An action in a workflow run can't trigger a new workflow run. For
>   example, if an action pushes code using the repository's `GITHUB_TOKEN`,
>   a new workflow will not run even when the repository contains a
>   workflow configured to run when `push` events occur.

So basically, events that originate from a workflow cannot trigger other workflows.

---

An alternative would be to use a [scheduled](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#scheduled-events-schedule) workflow that checks every couple hours or so and does the validation.

```
on:
  schedule:
    - cron:  '0 0/2 * * *'
```